# Use Release.Name in values.yaml in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to use stable/fluent-bit as a sub-chart in my chart. That chart has a value in values.yaml:

```
backend:
  es:
    host: elasticsearch
```

How can I set the value of backend.es.host as something like {Release.Name}-elasticsearch without making changes to the fluent-bit chart?

Comment: Apparently, it is a widely famous feature request, but there had no inclination from the community to implement: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492 . At my workplace, we used custom variables to be replaced by our CI/CD pipelines, ie., one layer above helm chart value files.

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
{{ tpl .Release.Name . }}-elasticsearch
```

Comment: This will not work if just written as-is into `values.yaml` or a `helm install -f` file; you need to modify the template code, which the question is trying to avoid.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -7):

This should work:

```
{{ tpl .Release.Name }}-elasticsearch
```

Comment: It does not if you set it in values.yaml